# R Regression with different null hypothesis

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I have a series of regressions where I would like to execute different null hypotheses in the same regression.
This means that I would like to test whether one independent variable is equal to 1 and the other equal to 0.

```
netew3 <- summary(lm(ewvw[,3]-factors$RF ~ factors$Mkt.RF + factors$SMB + factors$HML + factors$MOM, na.action = na.exclude), data = ewvw)
```

I would like to test whether the first variable (factors$Mkt.RF) is equal to 1 and the others (SMB, HML, and MOM) are equal to zero.

Thank you in advance for your help.
Best
PL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`summary()` of an `lm`-object gives you p-values for all coefficients under the null hypotheses that each coefficient equals 0. However, it also gives you all necessary information to conduct your own test with a different null hypothesis, e.g. that coefficients are 1.

[This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/344006/understanding-t-test-for-linear-regression) is one of many places where t-test of regression coefficients is explained in detail. Essentially, you get the t-value by calculating `(estimate - reference) / SE`. `SE` is the standard error and `reference` being the assumed value of the coefficient under the null hypothesis (usually 0). So all you have to do is change the latter value from 0 to 1 and you got your t-value.

I automated this in a function below. `h0.value` is your assumed value under the null hypothesis. You can check if it works properly with your data/model by running it with `h0.value = 0` and compare the result to what you get from `summary()`. If it works, use it with `h0.value = 1`.

```
estim_test <- function(lm.mod, h0.value = 0) {
  coefm <- as.data.frame(summary(lm.mod)$coefficients)
  n <- length(lm.mod$residuals)
  coefm$`t value` <- (coefm$Estimate - h0.value)/coefm$`Std. Error`
  coefm$`Pr(>|t|)` <- 2*pt(-abs(coefm$`t value`), df=lm.mod$df.residual)
  coefm
}

# Testing the function
data("swiss")
mod1 <- lm(Fertility ~ Agriculture + Education + Catholic, data=swiss)
summary(mod1)
estim_test(mod1, h0.value=0)
estim_test(mod1, h0.value=1)
```